# Excel VBA SQL error, Connection failed

Tags: vba, excel, ms-jet-ace

I get the following error when I try to run an internal sql query in my Excel spreadsheet.

> Error 2147467259 - Method of 'Execute' object' _Connection' failed.

Also when I run the code with breakpoints, I can get an automation error. I am querying in Excel 2013 (15.0.5023.1000).

```
With conn_obj
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & report_name & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With

On Error GoTo err_SQL
SQL = query

Set rs = conn_obj.Execute(SQL)  'error here
```

Update: I replaced the above code with the below, I am getting an error on

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB Specification.

```
Dim sSQLString As String
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

Let DBPath = report_name 'Path here
Let sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;';"

Conn.Open sconnect
sSQLString = query ' query here
mrs.Open sSQLString, Conn
```

Comment: What is the value of `report_name` when it fails?

Comment: @TimWilliams , the value of report_name is path of the file, ie \\path\stack\overflow.xlsb

Answer (score 0):

could you try changing the below

```
 "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
```

to

```
  "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
```

if not advise what report_name is equal to.

alternatively try the below:

```
    Dim sSQLString As String
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
Let DBPath = "" 'Path here
Let sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPath & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;';"
Conn.Open sconnect
sSQLString = "" ' query here
mrs.Open sSQLString, Conn
```

Comment: seems like I get the same error, either connection failed or automation error. ?Report_name is equal to the path name of the file.

Comment: what line is it breaking on?

Comment: `Set rs = conn_obj.Execute(SQL)`    hovering over rs = nothing.

Comment: ive added an alternative, can you try?

Comment: Tried it, getting a new error now, ive updated my question with the results. I replaced that section of code with your alternative and getting a new error, For `DBPath` i used `report name` from my original code, not sure if that was correct, and for sSQLString i used `query` from my original code.

Comment: I'm assuming my Dbpath is wrong, where can I find my Db path? This is an internal sql query between sheets btw.

Comment: Why did you change *ACE.OLEDB.12.0* for older *Jet.OLEDB.4.0*?